# Speech to text audio recording

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text

I've cross browser code for recording audio and encode in to mp3 format. Is it possible to make speech to text audio right from buffer of recording in same time with mp3 encoding?

```
  function encode (e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)) {
    let samplesMono = convertBuffer(arrayBuffer)
    let remaining = samplesMono.length
    for (let i = 0; remaining >= 0; i += maxSamples) {
      var left = samplesMono.subarray(i, i + maxSamples)
      var data = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(left)
      mp3Data.push(data)
      remaining -= maxSamples
    }
  }

  function convertBuffer (arrayBuffer) {
    var data = new Float32Array(arrayBuffer)
    var out = new Int16Array(arrayBuffer.length)
    floatTo16BitPCM(data, out)
    return out
  }
```

Now I'm using "webkitSpeechRecognition" function, but I need cross browser speech to text code, and it will be fine if audio recording buffer value possible to send to any speech to text server like google. I think webkitSpeechRecognition do it by same way.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of the project with Amazon transcribe. https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/aws/amazon-transcribe-streaming-now-supports-websockets/

Amazon do speech to text with simple javascript by websocket.